# Python: Use one list to search another list and pull corresponding rows

Tags: python, list, csv

I am stuck. I have a list of strings, and I want to search through a bigger list that has additional columns associated with those strings, and put the strings from my first list into a new file with their associated values from the second list (ie. take the whole row where there is a string match).

This is what I have so far

```
from sys import argv

script, filename, filename2, outputfile = argv

import csv #program to help manipulate csv files
with open(filename,'rU') as fin1, open(filename2, 'rU') as fin2, open (outputfile,'w') as fout: #simplifies opening and closing a file into one line

for row in fin1:
    gene = row[0]

writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=',')       #dialect must be specified, csv file so it is a ,
    for gene in csv.reader(fin1, delimiter=','):
        for row in csv.reader(fin2, delimiter=','):
            if gene == row[4]: 
                writer.writerow(row)
                break
```

Thank you

Comment: You need to help yourself first, think what you can do that can make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Maybe you can put sample inputs and outputs to help make the question each to understand.

Comment: For example, Python is sensitive to white spaces, so you need to make sure the source code you paste is indented correctly.

Comment: Sure, let's say filename contains:
Arp
Nelf
MyoD

Filename2 contains: 

Arp, 4, 5
Me, 1, 2
Hi, 2, 6
MyoD, 5, 1
No, 3, 4
Nelf, 2, 1

I want to use the first list to search through the second and put in a new file:
Arp, 4, 5
MyoD, 5, 1
Nelf, 2, 1

Comment: And you can explain what are `fin1` and `fin2` for, I know one of them is the bigger list, but it would help if you clarify in your question.

Comment: Yes, sorry. fin1 is smaller list. fin2 is bigger table.

Comment: I think maybe I am off track with my code. I am a beginner at this and am trying hard to figure it out. Before I added in "for row in fin1:
        gene = row[0]" to the code, it was spitting out a blank doc. Not it is also erroring.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sys import argv

script, filename, filename2, outputfile = argv

import csv # program to help manipulate csv files with open(filename,'rU') as fin1, open(outputfile,'w') as fout:  # simplifies opening and closing a file into one line
    writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=',')       # dialect must be specified, csv file so it is a ,
    for row_fin1 in csv.reader(fin1, delimiter=','):
        gene = row_fin1[0]
        with open(filename2, 'rU') as fin2:
            for row_fin2 in csv.reader(fin2, delimiter=','):
                if gene == row_fin2[4]:
                    writer.writerow(row_fin2)
                    break
```

You need to open and close the fin2 each time, because csv reader reads only in forward direction and cant go back.
Hope this helps.

Comment: @WeaselFox, I completely agree with you but there are limitations to csv module. A much better would be to read all the row[0] from fin1 in a list, then loop through rows of csv_reader of fin2, keep checking if desired item (row[4]) is in that list and process if true.